# Url parameters is undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have this controller

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers")
.controller("MainTagNavigatorController_P2",function($scope, $location) {   
    var urlParams = $location.search(); 
    $scope.tag = urlParams['source-tag'];

    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() { 

    });
```

here is navigation

```
  .state('tags-navigation-p2', {
    url: "/tags-navigation-p2",
    templateUrl: 'templates/MainTagNavigators/tags-navigation-p2.html',
    controller: 'MainTagNavigatorController_P2'
  })
```

here is typical navigation

page1 -> tags-navigation-p2?source-tag="xyz" -> p3

problem is when i come to `page1` from `page3` using `$state.go('page1');`
and again try to go to `tags-navigation-p2` from `page1` it shows `urlParams['source-tag'];` `undefined`

Comment: You should do `var urlParams = $location.search;` instead of assigning `search` method reference

Answer (score 0):

You shall define what parameters you are expecting in state configuration:

```
.state('tags-navigation-p2', {
    url: "/tags-navigation-p2?sourceTag",
    templateUrl: 'templates/MainTagNavigators/tags-navigation-p2.html',
    controller: 'MainTagNavigatorController_P2'
})
```

Then get this parameter using `$stateParams`

```
angular.module("mobApp.controllers")
    .controller("MainTagNavigatorController_P2", function ($scope, $stateParams) {   
        // $stateParams.sourceTag
    });
```

Comment: i guess the issue is with `$state.go('page1');` cos if i go by pressing back button it works well. but because of`$state.go('page1');` its not working as expected

Comment: You shall pass parameter: `$scope.go('tags-navigation-p2', { sourceTag: 'smth' })`

Comment: @karaxuna the above state.go wouldn't pass parameter because it will fail to locate route as `sourceTag` is not mentioned in URL..

Answer (score 0):

The search params from `$location.search()` are normalized, so it would be `urlParams.searchTag`.